# What is the use of transaction.commit_unless_managed() python

Tags: python, mysql, django

What is the use of `transaction.commit_unless_managed()` in python?

I don’t know more about transaction. In my code I have seen a function   `transaction.commit_unless_managed()`, but I don’t know what is the use of `commit_unless_managed()`

```
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

Please explain what is the use of `commit_unless_managed()`?
and difference between normal `commit` and `commit_unless_managed()`

Answer (score 5):

`commit_unless_managed` is a function that does kind of what it talks about.  It issues a transaction commit if the code is in an unmanaged transaction block.  n.b.  `commit_unless_managed` was removed in Django 1.8.

Why would you use it?  If you ever have a common function that can be called in both a managed transaction block as well as an unmanaged transaction block, you can use `commit_unless_managed` so that the unmanaged transaction code path issues the commit.  For example:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually()
def managed():
    test()

@transaction.autocommit()
def unmanaged():
    test()

def test():
    # process some db commands
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

In this example `test` will issue a commit when called from `unmanaged` but not when called from `managed`.